# C# ASP.NET AJAX - random number changes, but only want it to change when "new question" button clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I didn't want to over-complicate the question, but here goes...
I have a file of questions and answers. I want to use C# ASP.NET Core MVC to get question from file, format as JSON, return question value to webpage using AJAX. The question is displayed by clicking a button which runs the C# method by connecting to it with a Route[] statement. Then, also in AJAX on the same webpage, the user can submit their answer. If they are correct, it will tell them. This works if no RANDOM number is involved. The random number simply selects the line of the text-file containing the questions - that's all it does! However, the catch-22 is that when the user clicks on the "ANSWER" button to submit their answer, it re-runs the C# method, which generates a new random number, so has a good chance of selecting a different line from the file, hence containing a different answer and then it tells the user they got it wrong, even though they were correct...
The code on the webpage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {  //When document loads, function is ready (this includes ALL of the functions below!)

            $('#showQ').click(function () {
                //Block of code that uses AJAX to DISPLAY questions from Controllers/DemoController.cs/answerQuestion()
                $.ajax(
                    {   //Start of the actual AJAX request code...
                        type: 'GET',    //Use GET method to send values
                        url: '/demo/answerQuestion/',//The location of the method (Controllers/DemoController.cs/answerQuestion)
                        success: function (result) {    //If function is successful, it will display the result
                            $('#displayQ').html(result);  //If the code above is successful, it will display the question inside id="displayQ"
                        }
                    }
                )
            });
            //Block of code that uses AJAX to ANSWER questions from Controllers/DemoController.cs/answerQuestion()
            $('#answerQ').click(function () {   //When answerQ button is clicked, run this function...
                var answer = $('#answer').val();  //var answer = id="answer" field value when answerQ submit button is pressed
                $.ajax(
                    {   //Start of the actual AJAX request code...
                        type: 'GET',    //Use GET method to send values
                        url: '/demo/answerQuestion/' + answer, //Submit answer value to answerQuestion
                        success: function (result) {
                            $('#displayAns').html(result);  //If the code above is successful, it will send the answer and display result in id="displayAns"
                        }
                    }
                )
            });
        }); //End of $(document).ready(function...

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Question...</legend>
        <br />
        <input type="button" value="Click for question" id="showQ" />
        <br />
        <span id="displayQ"></span>
        <br />
        Answer: <input type="text" id="answer" />
        <br />
        <input type="button" value="Click to submit answer" id="answerQ" />
        <br />
        <span id="displayAns"></span>
        <br />
    </fieldset>

</body>
</html>
```

The C# methods that pick up the values from AJAX...

```
[Route("answerQuestion")]
        [Route("answerQuestion/{answer}")]
        public IActionResult AnswerQuestion(string answer)
        {
            //Need to think of a way to get this to only run when "Next question" button is clicked and not when answer provided!
            //Problem is, if I make it so it only runs if "answer" is not set, then it complains that variable is undefined!
            //It's a bit of a catch-22!!!
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int randomNumber = rnd.Next(0, 10);

            string path = @"C:\Users\aposi\Desktop\csharpweb\HOWMVCWORKS\quizquestions.txt";
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
            {
                string[] allLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);
                string randomLine = allLines[randomNumber];
                string removedSlashN = randomLine.Replace("\n", "");
                string removedWhitespace = removedSlashN.Replace(" ", "");
                string[] separatedout = removedWhitespace.Split("|"); //Has to be string array data-type to work with Split() function
                string songname = separatedout[0];
                char songletter = songname[0];
                string artist = separatedout[1];

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(answer))
                {
                    return new JsonResult("Artist: " + artist + "First letter of songname: " + songletter);
                }
                else if (answer == songname)
                {
                        return new JsonResult("Well done! You guessed correctly that the song name is: " + songname);
                }
                else if (answer != songname)
                {
                        return new JsonResult("Sorry! You got it wrong! The song name was... " + songname);
                }
                else
                {
                    return new JsonResult("Something went wrong!!!");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return new JsonResult("No question file found!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you may be over complicating this. Why use the same endpoint to `get` the question as the one you `post` the answer to?

Comment: As @ChiefTwoPencils said, you are calling the same code twice. If you still want to use GET for the answer just make sure you change the route. For submitting answers it should be a post.  /getQuestion and /answerQuestion.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways you can go about it.

1. Split this into two calls:

   - `GetQuestion`, which returns the line number of the question with the question and
   - `AnswerQuestion`, which accepts the line number, and that's the line where you look for the answer.
2. Keep it with one call where you return the line number of the question with the question. Then you pass the line number back with the answer, and pull the answer from that line number and compare with their answer. Then you create a random number to find a new question.
3. Keep it with one call, but return the answer with the question. You just keep that in your JavaScript until the user answers. Then you don't even need to make a new AJAX request to know if they were right.

I would keep it in one call only because using two would require, well, two requests, and loading the file twice.

But to keep it as one call, you would need to create a class and return that instead of just a string that gets displayed.

```
public class Question {
    public string Question { get; set; }

    // if you want to send the answer
    public string Answer { get; set; }

    // if you don't want to send the answer
    public int LineNumber { get; set; }

    // text you show in response to their answer. e.g. "Well done! ..."
    public string ResponseText { get; set; }
}
```

Then you return that class, with the properties set however you need depending on what happened. For example, if they answered correctly, it would look something like:

```
return new JsonResult(new Question {
    Question = $"Artist: {artist} First letter of song name: {songletter}",
    Answer = answer, //if you want
    LineNumber = randomNumber,
    ResponseText = $"Well done! You guessed correctly that the song name is: {songname}"
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I have had it as two separate methods to handle the get question and get answer. I will experiment with each of your suggestions because I'm still in the process of learning C# and AJAX, so sometimes how I think it should work, doesn't work, or I get errors and don't understand why just yet. Thank you for your time, I'll post up the code when I get it all working so others may benefit.